# It it possible to do multiprocessing within a loop in python 3.2?

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python (3.2) to multiprocess (ubuntu) to solve a massive search problem. Basically I want to take a list, take out the first item, find all other items that have the same properties as the object, join the found items and the target item into one list, remove them from the original list, and (loop) do it all again. The multiprocessing is meant to divide the work across processors. The code executes once with no problem. It will, in fact, loop as well, as the exception is ignored, and seems to be doing a good job. But within 30 seconds, it's used up nearly all my 16GB of RAM.

My two concerns so far are 1) I get "Exception AssertionError: AssertionError('can only test a child process',) in  ignored" as soon as I loop (and I get a lot of them). Along with this is massive amount of RAM usage (which, I think might be related, not sure). AND 2) It doesn't even seem to be carrying out the search in parallel when I use a larger data set.

My code looks like:

```
class triangleListWorker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, work_queue, target, results,start):
        super().__init__()
        self.work_queue = work_queue
        self.results = results
        self.target = target
        self.startIndex = start
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                searching = self.work_queue.get()
                self.do_search(searching)

            finally:
                self.work_queue.task_done()

    def do_search(self,searching):
        for x in range(len(searching)):
            if self.target.same_plane(searching[x]):
                self.results.append(self.startIndex+x)
```

What I'm trying to do here is used Manager().list() to store all the indexes where the target object and the searched object exist on the same plane.

```
    def do_multi_find_connections(self, target,searchList):
        work_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        #results= multiprocessing.Queue()

        cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        results = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
        range_per_process = len(searchList) // cpu_count
        start,end = 0, range_per_process + (len(searchList) % cpu_count)
        for i in range(cpu_count):
            worker = triangleListWorker(work_queue,target,results,start)
            worker.daemon = True
            worker.start()
        for x in range(cpu_count):
            searchsub = [searchList[x] for x in range(start,end)]
            work_queue.put(searchList[start:end])
            #work_queue.put(searchList[start:end])
            start,end = end, end + range_per_process
            print(start,end)

        work_queue.join()
        print( "can continue...")

        return results

    def find_connections(self, triangle_list,doMultiProcessing):
        tlist = [x for x in triangle_list]
        print("len tlist", len(tlist))
        results = []
        self.byPlane = []
        if doMultiProcessing:
            while len(tlist) > 0:
                results = []
                target = tlist[0]
                #print("target",tcopy[0])
                self.do_multi_find_connections(target,tlist)

                results = self.do_multi_find_connections(target,tlist)#list of indexes
                plane = []

                print(len(results))
                print(results)
                for x in results:
                    plane.append(tlist[x])
                new_tlist = [tlist[x] for x in range(len(tlist)) if not x in results]
                print(len(new_tlist))
                tlist = new_tlist

                self.byPlane.append(plane)

##                self.byPlane.append(plane)
##                tlist = []
```

This code(maybe a little ugly) is supposed to loop to find the next plane, and exhaust everything else that's in the plane by calling the function above it (which does the multiprocessing).

Running on Ubuntu 11.04 64, python 3.2.

Comment: Ooops. The line: Except "AssertionError" was not supposed to be in there.. it was a note to myself to try tomorrow morning when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Sounds like you are spawning infinite number of processes and exhaust the computer RAM. Put a print to the start of each process and make sure you have only CPU_COUNT + 1 process spawned.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop, I think the intended pattern for the `multiprocessing` module is to create a [`Pool`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) and use the [`Pool.map_async`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) method.  IOW, convert your loop to some sort of iterator (probably a [generator](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/classes.html#generators) method).  Then pass the equivalent of your `do_search` method in as the function and your iterator to `map_async`.

Comment: I'm not sure it will quite work for what I want. I did code it using a pool and it works BUT I still need the loop because I have to group everything in the list that I'm searching through. My method has been to take the first item and then search the whole list (multiprocessing) to find all things that belong with it (i.e. on the same plane). I use the loop to grab another target. While this method has produced no errors, it doesn't seem to use my processors at capacity - which I find curious. Also, it uses about 20GB of RAM, which would be fine but the SWAP on linux doesn't seem to get freed

Comment: And thank you. (sorry, ran out of characters). I will use this solution if I don't write a better one today :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pool class in multiprocessing :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=5)
valuesProcessed = pool.map(someFunction, valuesToProcess)
```